# How would you lock an SQLite database for testing?

Tags: python, sqlite, locking

I've got an application that uses SQLite and occasionaly it crashes due to the database being locked. I know I should migrate it to something else, but it's not possible right now so I need to implement a retry mechanism.

However, in order to do this I need to be able to lock some test database for testing and I don't know how it happens during runtime. Do you know how I can purposly create such a lock so that I can write code handling it?

Comment: @JonSG it seems! Thanks! It didn't pop up in the suggestions. I guess I should review my search skills ;-]

Comment: No worries my friend.  I actually did not try it before I recommended it. Hopefully it allows you to test what you need to